# Importing loguru in Python 3.11 ModuleNotFound

Tags: loguru

I already installed loguru and everything looks fine.

However, everytime I try to import it, I get the message ModuleNotfound. I have Python 3.11, and this is only happening with this package.

Does anyone knows what is the problem and how can i solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It turned out it was not loguru specific at all. If you are using a venv and just added loguru be sure to pick the right interpreter. For some reason when I added loguru poetry changed it back to the default one and so pyton gave me the aforementioned error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).